# Map alt-e to ctrl-Tab. Mint, Xfce

Tags: keyboard, xdotool

I have Linux Mint, Xfce.

I want to change tabs in Firefox by pressing Alt-e, rather than the default Ctrl-Tab.

In order to do that I must remap those keys in the Xfce UI.

In Xfce I can map a key to run a bash script here:
https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/keyboard
The bash script then runs xdotool, in order to press ctrl+Tab.

The key mapping that runs bash script works.

Now how to write the actual xdotool script, that seems to be no small feat. The following code freezes the system, needing a reboot:

```
xdotool keydown ctrl+Tab;
xdotool keyup Tab;
```

I have tried many other configurations, following forums found via googling. I tried adding sleep 0.1 infront and in between. As well as the xdotool --delay option.

Nothing seems to work.

How do I do this xdotool mapping?